# constexpr type forwarding fails

Tags: templates, c++11, constexpr

I am curious why the type check fails when it is forwarded using the constexpr function. I assume it has something to do with the substitution but dont know exactly because of what rule.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool isTypeIterator()
{
    return is_iterator<T>::value;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    static_assert(!is_iterator<decltype(vec)>::value, "It is clear why this works");
    static_assert(!is_type_iterator<decltype(vec)>, "I wonder why this is reversed");
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `isTypeIterator<decltype(vec)>()`? And did you add parentheses to the function call? Else you would be evaluating the function pointer, which is always true.

Comment: If you really are calling the function rather than comparing its function pointer, this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `is_type_iterator<decltype(vec)>` is a non-null pointer to a function, not a call to a function. Use `is_type_iterator<decltype(vec)>()` to get the expected result.

Or if you want to keep the syntax without parentheses, you can try C++14 variable templates:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_type_iterator = is_iterator<T>::value;
```